# how to make Inheritance dependence

Tags: c++

I'm triying to make this exercise:

> There are different types of employees: regular
>   workers,supervisors,board members which are specific types of
>   supervisors
>
> Track the number of objects of type regular worker.
>
> Each employee has its name and surname and can introduce himself.
>
> Each employee object has its own worker id which is assigned to him
>   while it is created
>
> The salary is calculated is specific way depending on the  type of the
>   employee.
>
> Each employee can have its direct supervisor which can be any 
>   supervisor(it means that for example a board member can be a
>   supervisor of regular worker)

Now i had made all of point, exclude the last point:

```
class Employees
{
public:
    static int  workerid;
    int salary;


    Employees(){
        workerid += 1;
    }
    void introduce(){
        cout << "the name is:" << name << "and surname" << surname << endl;

    }


};

int Employees::workerid = 0;

class Supervisors :public Employees{
public:

    Supervisors(){
        salary = 1000;
    }


};
class BoardMembers : public Supervisors{
public:
    BoardMembers(){
        salary = 1200;
    }


};
class RegularWorkers :public Employees{
public:
    static int number;
    Supervisors *supervisor;
    RegularWorkers(Supervisors supervisor){
        this->supervisor = &supervisor;
        number += 1;
        salary = 600;
    }


};
int RegularWorkers::number = 0;
```

(i think until the last point is ok), but for the last point I need one id of the supervisor but how to made the supervisor or boardemember assign to the regularworker?

Thank you & best regards

Comment: Instead of `int idofsupervisor;`, you can take `Supervisors *supervisor;`. Whenever you need id of supervisor, just use `supervisor->id`. Now add this `supervisor` object as the constructor argument for `class RegularWorkers`

Comment: `introduce` is supposed to output the name, not change it. (Do you know what it means to "introduce yourself" to someone?) And the last point says each *employee*, not each *regular worker*. The "any supervisor" specification suggests that you're expected to use the `Supervisor` class to indicate who's the supervisor, not an id. (I suspect you covered pointers relatively recently.)

Comment: Hello, thank you for ur repliies, i change the metod introduce to saw the name and surname, but i have one question how to is possible introduce the name and surname in the Employees constructor without change the order class.@molbdnilo

Comment: i realize the change of supervisor, but i dont know if is what you meant  @MohitJain

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark.  Make sure all of your questions that have been answered have answers accepted. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the employee class by adding a `Supervisor`

```
Supervisor *supervisor;
```

And then overload the Employee constructor to accept type `Supervisor` and set them equal to each other.

```
Employees(Supervisor *s){
    supervisor = s;
    workerid += 1;
}
```

Then you can access the Supervisor's ID by using

```
supervisor->ID
```

Also you may want to include `name` and `surname` as member variables and initialize those as well in the constructor.  To add to the previous constructor it might look like this.

```
Employees(Supervisor *s, string sName, string sSurname){
    name = sName;
    surname = sSurname;
    supervisor = s;
    workerid += 1;
}
```

Comment: so please mark his answer as an 'Answer' and give him an up-vote.